# Cannot save C:\Users\FlapPyBird-master\flappy.py. Unable to create a backup file (flappy.py~). The file left unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pycharm

I've copied a directory from github and imported it into Pycharm. Now, I wanted to change the code a little bit. But then this error occured:

Cannot save C:\Users\FlapPyBird-master\flappy.py.
Unable to create a backup file (flappy.py~).
The file left unchanged.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not be ever edited.

The behavior is expected, these files must not be edited. this is marked as read-only. If you want to edit files there (you shouldn't, though), you have two options:

1. change the directory permissions
2. disable creating a backup

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\FlapPyBird-master\` is an unusual place to put a git repository. By convention, the subfolders in that location should be the home folders of different users on your system.

If you right-click `C:\Users` in explorer, and go to Properties->Security, you can see that the folder is likely only editable ("write") by the administrator. Since Pycharm runs in your user's permission, by default it isn't able to edit these locations. (This is part of why your computer will ask you to grant permission when you install software to `C:\Program Files`, because your user account does not typically have permission to write there)

If you instead place the file in `C:\Users\[your username here]\FlapPyBird-master` (or better yet, something like `C:\Users\[your username here]\Documents\programming_projects\FlapPyBird-master`), you'll see that the permissions are already configured to let you edit files there.

If you MUST place the directory in `C:\Users`, you can right-click->Properties->Security->Edit->Add... and give yourself access this way.